# Shrinking width not height

Tags: html, css

I am over my head, on this one. This is my first website attempt (bweekleydotcom) and I want to retain my header bars height but I want the weight resize for screen size? My carousel works fine my background works fine but my header does not.

**HTML** (currently not in it's own div should it be)?

```
<img src="images/header.png" class="img-responsive bwheaderbkg" alt="header.png">
```

**CSS**

```
.bwheaderbkg {
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    top: -16px;
    left: -25px;
    min-width: 1600px;
}
```

Comment: min-width: 1600px?

Comment: An example of what you were trying to achieve would help

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking.. If you want your image size to be set based on monitor width - use `vw` attribute.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe width: 100%?

Comment: Define the width in % or vw, and after it will resize.

Comment: Thanks guys I will give these a try over my lunch hour. I have played around with this for 2 days and what seems like it should be so simple is kicking my butt. I thought I had my site just the way I wanted it look wise till I realized one could scroll to the right and see header bar and white space.